# Torque pbs queue system runs queue in reverse

Tags: queue, torque, pbs

I have a small compute cluster set up on Redhat 7.1.
It runs the PBS torque queue system with version 5.1.1.

When I queue several jobs it starts to run the jobs in "backwards" priority. It starts with the job which was submitted last.

Is there any setting which changes this behaviour so that the first job submitted starts first?